# Using <br/> within <p>

Tags: php, html, phpword

I use https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

When I use tab `<br/>` in html without other tags - it's ok. But if it is wrapped by p, in result br
is not replaced by line break in docx file. How fix it?

```
    $html .= '<p>line1<br/>lin2</p>';

    $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    $section = $phpWord->addSection();

    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html);

    $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
    $objWriter->save($fileName);
```

Context
PHP version: 5.4
PHPWord version: 0.14

Example:

```
 $html = '<p>line1<br/>line2</p><p>line3<br/>line4</p>'
```

I want in docx result:

line1
line2

line3
line4

But now have:

line1
line2

line3
line4

Issue: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1370

Comment: what about just a <br> without the closing tag=

Comment: It's not work:
error in DOMDocument::loadXML() because <br> is not valid tag

Comment: And what error do you get with <br/>?

Comment: No error, but in result file I have 
"line1line2"
instead of 
"line1[line break]line2"

Comment: why not just use two `<p>`? they'll drop ?

Comment: PhpWord does not support `<br>`. It supports `<p>,<h1>,<h2>,<h3>,<h4>,<h5>,<h6>,<strong>,<em>,<sup>,<sub>,<table>,<tr>,<td>,<ul>,<ol>,<li>`.

Comment: What about newline with regex \n?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden
PhpWord supports `<br>` - https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/4a530d1d97b064b87d9e2a1cc64cab996246569c/src/PhpWord/Shared/Html.php#L116

Comment: @RasmusBidstrup It does not work too

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs
It is difficult because p tags have own special styles
In my case I need only line break by br-tag

Comment: @t.niese Thanks, I added links

Comment: did you try with the dev-develop version? This was fixed in the upcoming 0.15

Comment: @troosan I tried to use dev-develop version by composer but it does not work too. I saw that you change src/PhpWord/Reader/Word2007/AbstractPart.php file. But I tried read not doc-file, I tried to read html-file - I have error while converting from html to .docx file

Comment: @Mike please check HtmlTest::testParseLineBreak, it's doing exactly that